# Using .Where() on a List

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

Assuming the two following possible blocks of code inside of a view, with a model passed to it using something like `return View(db.Products.Find(id));`

```
List<UserReview> reviews = Model.UserReviews.OrderByDescending(ur => ur.Date).ToList();
if (myUserReview != null)
    reviews = reviews.Where(ur => ur.Id != myUserReview.Id).ToList();
```

```
IEnumerable<UserReview> reviews = Model.UserReviews.OrderByDescending(ur => ur.Date);
if (myUserReview != null)
    reviews = reviews.Where(ur => ur.Id != myUserReview.Id);
```

What are the performance implications between the two? By this point, is all of the product related data in memory, including its navigation properties? Does using `ToList()` in this instance matter at all? If not, is there a better approach to using Linq queries on a `List` without having to call `ToList()` every time, or is this the typical way one would do it?

Comment: As I understand it, the query itself will not do anything until it is materialized (run) - either by iterating over it or calling some extension method (like `.ToList()`) that will execute it.  So you're original assertion (that all the data is in memory) is not correct.  Then again, I could be mistaken.

Comment: Why the aspö.net mvc tag? Is any line of code here relevant to ASP.NET?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Read http://blogs.msdn.com/b/charlie/archive/2007/12/09/deferred-execution.aspx

Deferred execution is one of the many marvels intrinsic to linq.  The short version is that your data is never touched (it remains idle in the source be that in-memory, or in-database, or wherever).  When you construct a linq query all you are doing is creating an IEnumerable class that is 'capable' of enumerating your data.  The work doesn't begin until you actually start enumerating and then each piece of data comes all the way from the source, through the pipeline, and is serviced by your code one item at a time.  If you break your loop early, you have saved some work - later items are never processed.  That's the simple version.

Some linq operations cannot work this way.  Orderby is the best example.  Orderby has to know every piece of data because it possible that the last piece retrieved from the source very well could be the first piece that you are supposed to get.  So when an operation such as orderby is in the pipe, it will actually cache your dataset internally.  So all data has been pulled from the source, and has gone through the pipeline, up to the orderby, and then the orderby becomes your new temporary data source for any operations that come afterwards in the expression.  Even so, orderby tries as much as possible to follow the deferred execution paradigm by waiting until the last possible moment to build its cache.  Including orderby in your query still doesn't do any work, immediately, but the work begins once you start enumerating.

**To answer your question directly**, your call to ToList is doing exactly that.  OrderByDescending is caching the data from your datasource => ToList additionally persists it into a variable that you can actually touch (reviews) => where starts pulling records one at a time from reviews, and if it matches then your final ToList call is storing the results into yet another list in memory.

Beyond the memory implications, ToList is additionally thwarting deferred execution because it also STOPS the processing of your view at the time of the call, to entirely process that entire linq expression, in order to build its in-memory representation of the results.

Now none of this is a real big deal if the number of records we're talking about are in the dozens.  You'll never notice the difference at runtime because it happens so quick.  But when dealing with large scale datasets, deferring as much as possible for as long as possible in hopes that something will happen allowing you to cancel a full enumeration... in addition to the memory savings...  gold.

In your version without ToList:  OrderByDescending will still cache a copy of your dataset as processed through the pipeline up to that point, internally, sorted of course.  That's ok, you gotta do what you gotta do.  But that doesn't happen until you actually try to retrieve your first record later in your view.  Once that cache is complete, you get your first record, and for every next record you are then pulling from that cache, checking against the where clause, you get it or you don't based upon that where and have saved a couple of in memory copies and a lot of work.

Magically, I bet even your lead-in of `db.Products.Find(id)` doesn't even start spinning until your view starts enumerating (if not using ToList).  If db.Products is a Linq2SQL datasource, then every other element you've specified will reduce into SQL verbiage, and your entire expression will be deferred.

Hope this helps!  Read further on Deferred Execution.  And if you want to know 'how' that works, look into c# iterators (yield return).  There's a page somewhere on MSDN that I'm having trouble finding that contains the common linq operations, and whether they defer execution or not.  I'll update if I can track that down.

/***edit***/ to clarify - all of the above is in the context of raw linq, or Linq2Objects.  Until we find that page, common sense will tell you how it works.  If you close your eyes and imagine implementing orderby, or any other linq operation, if you can't think of a way to implement it with 'yield return', or without caching, then execution is not likely deferred and a cache copy is likely and/or a full enumeration...  orderby, distinct, count, sum, etc...  Linq2SQL is a whole other can of worms.  Even in that context, ToList will still stop and process the whole expression and store the results because a list, is a list, and is in memory.  But Linq2SQL is uniquely capable of deferring many of those aforementioned clauses, and then some, by incorporating them into the generated SQL that is sent to the SQL server.  So even orderby can be deferred in this way because the clause will be pushed down into your original datasource and then ignored in the pipe.

Good luck ;)

Comment: This answer could be improved if you were more clear about the `OrderBy()` behavior. In particular, while calling the `OrderBy()` method is just like the other LINQ methods, in that nothing is enumerated when you call that particular method itself, and no doubt that's what you intended to convey, the wording in this answer _could_ be interpreted to mean the opposite. That is, some reads might get the impression that when you actually call `OrderBy()`, that's when the caching of the data occurs.

Comment: Thanks for the clarifying edits...answer looks even better now. +1 :)

Answer (score 1):

Not enough context to know for sure.

But `ToList()` *guarantees* that the data has been copied into memory, and your first example does that twice.

The second example *could* involve queryable data or some other on-demand scenario. Even if the original data was all already in memory and even if you only added a call to `ToList()` at the end, that would be one less copy in-memory than the first example.

And it's entirely possible that in the second example, by the time you get to the end of that little snippet, no actual processing of the original data has been done at all. In that case, the database might not even be queried until some code actually enumerates the final `reviews` value.

As for whether there's a "better" way to do it, not possible to say. You haven't defined "better". Personally, I tend to prefer the second example...why materialize data before you need it? But in some cases, you *do* want to force materialization. It just depends on the scenario.